# How can I diff two files in Perl?

Tags: perl, diff

I have two text files which need to have the same values.

```
$ diff A.txt B.txt
4a5
> I have this extra line.
$
```

Open files in Perl

```
open (ONE, "<A.txt");
open (TWO, "<B.txt");
```

How can I do such a diff from within Perl? Does Perl have a inbuilt diff or do I need to use the unix `diff` utility? I don't want to implement my own diff algorithm for this.

I do need the information as to where my files differ, but I do not need to use the unix `diff` utility necessarily. That was just an example.

Comment: Do you actually need the "diff" output or just a signal that the the files are identical or not? If all you want to do is to determine if the two files have the same content line by line, it is pretty easy to read them line by line in Perl and compare the lines, and exit with a complaint if a pair of lines don't match.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: I just need to find out that the files are identical or not. `diff` was just an example.

Comment: I'm confused: your comment to brian d foy appears to conflict with your other comments. To repeat Ira Baxter's question, do you simply need to know **whether the files differ**, or do you need details on **how they differ**.

Comment: Duplicate : [How can I use Perl to determine whether the contents of two files are identical?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847914/how-can-i-use-perl-to-determine-whether-the-contents-of-two-files-are-identical)

Comment: @FM: I need to know where they differ too, but I do not necessarily need to use the `diff` utility, is what I meant.

Comment: @Lazer: The simple read-line-and-compare loop will answer that question too if you simply count lines.

Answer (score 12):

You could try using [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Text-Diff-1.37/lib/Text/Diff.pm)

Alternatively, the UNIX utility could be an option.

Answer (score 5):

If I only needed to know that they were the same (i.e. not discover how they are different), I'd just use [Digest::MD5](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-MD5) to see if they come up with the same digest. There's a vanishingly small chance that two different files could have the same MD5 digest, so you might even try [Digest::SHA1](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-SHA1).

If you want to find out which lines are different, then you can use [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff), perhaps in conjunction with [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-File). However, there is also a *diff* program that comes with [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff) if you don't have a diff tool on your target platform. Although you can shell out to that, you might just want to copy what it does into a subroutine. Text::Diff is built on top of [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff), so it might already do want you want.

Comment: I need to know which all lines `diff` ed.

Comment: Well, then you should say that. In your comment to Ira you said otherwise.

Comment: There's zero chance of a collision if you read both files and compare each byte. Hashing is great for some things, such as comparing files over the network (without sending the whole file), or comparing thousands of files against each other. For comparing two files that are located on the same machine (at the same point in time), what is the advantage of hashing?

Comment: Well, you might save a lot of time. Let's say you have 1000 files. That's a lot of two-file combinations to check. Never mind that these files might be large. You can generate the hash just once for each file and do a simple comparison.

Comment: The hashing solution is obviously better if you want to compare each file several times. However, using it for a single comparison always gives you the worst-case performance scenario of having to scan all of both files.

Answer (score 2):

No, Perl doesn't have an inbuilt "diff" facility. Either you use an external module, or use Perl's data structures(hashes, arrays etc) or you create filehandles for both files, and iterate the files using the filehandle (while loops), comparing them line by line. This method assumes your files are sorted. Another not so elegant way is to call "diff" from Perl, but I advise against that.

Lastly, if Perl is not a must, just use the Unix `diff` utility (write a shell script).

Answer (score 0):

You can the core module `File::Compare` :

```perl
use File::Compare;
if (compare("file1","file2") == 0) {
    print "They're equal\n";
}
```

Documentation is [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/File/Compare.html).