# How can I compare two files and show differences in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, diff

I'm trying to write Perl script to compare the content of 2 files so that it would list out any differences seen.  Trying the following but I'm not sure how to continue further.  Note that following is only part of the script as I have sorted the content of the 2 files beforehand.  Thanks in advance.

```
open (FILE1, "log") || die ("Can't open file log for reading") ;
open (FILE2, "master") || die ("Can't open file master for reading") ;

@file1 = <FILE1> ;
@file2 = <FILE2> ;

#$perlcompare = (compare('log','master')== 0) ;
#die ("Log and master files are equal and match.\n") ;

if (@file1 eq @file2) {

print "Log and master are equal and match.\n" ;
} else  ????????????

exit 0;
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the files line by line and print the lines that are not matching? Can't you use diff utility in the OS or md5sum if you just want to know whether the files are same or not?

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581749/how-can-i-diff-two-files-in-perl

Comment: `@file1 eq @file2` only checks that they have the same number of lines.  `@file1 ~~ @file2` will compare the contents.  If you use Text::Diff, as Sinan answered, you don't need to do an extra check at all.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to stay within Perl, there is [File::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aCompare) which will just compare the files.

For showing differences, there is [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aDiff).

```
C:\Temp> cat file1
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
C:\Temp> cat file2
1
2
3
5
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Text::Diff;

my $diffs = diff 'file1' => 'file2';

print $diffs;
```

#### Output

```
C:\Temp> t
--- file1       Fri Nov 18 00:01:40 2011
+++ file2       Fri Nov 18 00:01:49 2011
@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
 1
 2
 3
-4
+5
-5
```

Comment: User asked to show the differences too, which it doesn't look like that module will do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Somehow I missed it the first time I read the question.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer, I tried to use the diff module as following, though it did compare, but I want the output so that it show only the unmatch stuff, such as I'll like to show file 1 (log) show extra what item or missing what item compare to file2. May I know any tips to work on this?                                                               open OUTPUT, ">output2" ;
$diffs = diff 'log' => 'list' ;
print OUTPUT $diffs ;
close OUTPUT ;

Answer (score 2):

If you can use anything else than perl, I would recommend diff(1) or comm(1)

```
comm -3 sorted-file-1 sorted-file-2
```

Comment: I have the 2 files named "log" and "master", tried by using --> comm -3 "log" "master" -2 but it flag me wih error.  is this command comes with predefined module?

Comment: I'm using the if (@file1 eq @file2) {  print "Log and master are equal and match.\n" ; } else XXXXX in my script, in fact it can execute correctly when the 2 file match.  I assume the "eq" command will return "0" when there is an unmatch.  So, was thinkking to set else when the condition is "0" then it will proceed to grab the unmatch string... but not sure how to proceed.  Also, was wondering if the "eq" command is checking throughout the whole document of it halt when it find the first unmatch.

Comment: What is your error ? comm comes with coreutils as I see on archlinux

Comment: @Grace `eq` will not compare the content of the arrays. Try `perl -we '@a=(1,2); @b=(3,4); print "yes" if @a eq @b;'` `eq` puts the arrays in scalar context, meaning that their size is compared, not their content. You *can* however compare the arrays with smart matching, e.g. `@a ~~ @b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

open (my $log, "<", "log") or die $!;
open (my $master, "<", "master") or die $!;
my @content_log=<$log>;
my @content_master=<$master>;

my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@content_log, \@content_master);    
my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;
my @firstonly = $lc->get_unique;
my @secondonly = $lc->get_complement;

print "Common Items:\n"."@intersection"."\n";
print "Items Only in First List:\n"."@firstonly"."\n";
print "Items Only in Second List:\n"."@secondonly"."\n";

print "log\n", $lc->get_unique,"\n"; 
print "master\n", $lc->get_complement,"\n"; 

close $log;
close $master;
```