# How to include a "diff" in a Perl test?

Tags: perl, testing, module, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use Perl to determine whether the contents of two files are identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847914/how-can-i-use-perl-to-determine-whether-the-contents-of-two-files-are-identical)

If I am writing a Perl module test, and for example I want to test that an output file is exactly what is expected, if I use an external command like `diff`, the test might fail on some operating systems which don't provide the `diff` command. What would be a simple way to do something like `diff` on files, which doesn't rely on external commands? I understand that there are modules on CPAN which can do file diffs, but I would rather not complicate the build process unless necessary.

Comment: Duplicate : [How can I use Perl to determine whether the contents of two files are identical?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847914/how-can-i-use-perl-to-determine-whether-the-contents-of-two-files-are-identical)

Comment: @Zaid: it's not an exact duplicate of that question but it is similar.

Comment: Closing this question as a duplicate is overenthusiastic busy-bodying at its worst. This isn't a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question on principle, since it (fairly obviously) isn't a duplicate of the other question. Why five people thought it was, I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[File::Compare](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aCompare), in core since 5.004.

Answer (score 5):

When testing and looking for differences in files or strings I always use [Test::Differences](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Test-Differences/lib/Test/Differences.pm) that uses [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Diff/lib/Text/Diff.pm). I know that you probably know that and you would like a non module solution, but looking for differences has many corner cases so is not trivial. Also I write this answer more for googlers (just in case you already know these modules).

I like the [table output](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Diff/lib/Text/Diff/Table.pm) of this module. It is very convenient when the differences are a small number.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just read and compare the two files in perl? Something like...

```
sub readfile
{
    local ($/) = undef;
    open READFILE, "<", $_[0]
        or die "Can't read '$_[0]': $!";
    my $contents = <READFILE>;
    close READFILE or die "Can't close '$_[0]': $!";
    return $contents;
}
$expected = readfile("expected_results");
$actual = readfile("actual_results");
if ($expected != $actual) {
    die "Got wrong results!";
}
```

(If you're concerned about multiple OS portability, you may also need to do something about line endings, either in your test program or here, because some OSs use CRLF instead of LF to separate lines in text files. If you want to handle it here, a regular expression replace will do the trick.)

Comment: I was hoping for something shorter.